# Move data to bottom row when text is a certain color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a terribly formatted dataset that is all on one row. They formatted it so that the information that should be in the first column of each row has Green text, and the following columns for that row have Red text. The problem is that there could be 1 - 5 columns for each row so I can't do it based on that.

I need to move the data to a new row each time it reaches a cell with green text. I have experience with C++ and a little javascript, but I know next to nothing about visual basic. I am working with excel 2013, and I can upload the file if that helps. Here is a comma separated demo of what I am trying to accomplish.

What it looks like right now:

G1,R1,R2,R3,G2,R4,G4,R5,R6,R7,R8,etc.

What I need it to look like:

G1,R1,R2,R3

G2,R4

G4,R5,R6,R7,R8
etc.

Comment: The primary problem is determining what numerical identifier Excel is using for `.Font.Color` or `.Font.ColorIndex`. Can you record a macro while coloring the font green then tap Alt+F8, Edit and report back what the color is being set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro code will reorganize your row of data putting each cell with a green font in column A. The shade of green currently being identified is 5296274.

```
Sub Collect_by_Color()
    Dim lRowWithData As Long, lColor As Long, c As Long, lc As Long

    lColor = 5296274
    lRowWithData = 3

    With ActiveSheet
        lc = .Cells(lRowWithData, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For c = lc To 2 Step -1 'assumes that the cell in column A is already in place
            Debug.Print .Cells(lRowWithData, c).Font.Color
            If .Cells(lRowWithData, c).Font.Color = lColor Then
                .Cells(lRowWithData, c).Resize(1, lc).Copy _
                  Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Cells(lRowWithData, c).Resize(1, lc).ClearContents
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Change the `lRowWithData` number to the row with your data. If you have not determined the color identifier, this will report back the font colors it finds to the Immediate Window in the VBE. Use Alt+F11 to get to the VBE and then Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Jeeped. I got moved onto a different project and wont be able to use this until tomorrow. I'll let you know how it goes. You're a lifesaver. Thank you so much!